# matplotlib draw only the image with desired resolution and dpi

Tags: python, matplotlib, collections

I've read all of the questions of stackoverflow about this thematic without success.
The code above it's the closest thing that I can get to a image without axes and borders.
I'm not able to control the image resolution, because the dpi when I open the image in gimp it's different from the one that I've chosen .
I'd like to have a final image with  7158 x 16392 with 72 dpi, without any borders or frames.

```
from stl import mesh
from matplotlib import collections
from matplotlib import pyplot

figure, axes = pyplot.subplots(frameon=False)
figure.set_size_inches(99.5,228)
# Read the STL file
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('2d_35MeshTest.STL')

axes.set_xlim(your_mesh.min_[0], your_mesh.max_[0])
axes.set_ylim(your_mesh.min_[1], your_mesh.max_[1])

axes.add_collection(collections.PolyCollection(your_mesh.vectors[:, :, :2], linewidth=1, 
    facecolors=(1,1,1),alpha=1, edgecolors=(1,0,0) ))

print your_mesh.vectors.shape
pyplot.gca().set_aspect('equal')

pyplot.axis('off')
ax = pyplot.Axes(figure, [0., 0., 1., 1.], )
figure.set_dpi(72)

figure.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
figure.subplots_adjust(top = 1)
figure.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
figure.subplots_adjust(left = 0)

figure.savefig('image_refined8.png', format='png', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches =  0.001)
```

The stl file is here [stl file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/2d_35MeshTest.STL)
The image output is [image output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/image_refined8.png)

Comment: I misunderstood your main intent. The dpi-issue doesn't exist, as long as the figure is  7158 x 16392 pixels. If you want that to happen, you should not use bbox_inches='tight', because that resizes the figure. You are also adding axes after you turn them off. BTW, the image is completely white to me, except for the axes and the transparent border (probably the pad_inches). I also can't seems to run your code. Where is `stl` coming from?

Comment: I've updated the code and the files. When I'm using the "tight", it doesn't fit right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your edit:

```
from stl import mesh
from matplotlib import collections
from matplotlib import pyplot

figure, axes = pyplot.subplots(frameon=False)
pixel_width = 7158  # ADDED
pixel_height = 16392  # ADDED
req_dpi = 72  # ADDED
figure.set_size_inches(pixel_width / float(req_dpi),  # MODIFIED
                       pixel_height / float(req_dpi))  # MODIFIED
# Read the STL file
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('2d_35MeshTest.STL')

axes.set_xlim(your_mesh.min_[0], your_mesh.max_[0])
axes.set_ylim(your_mesh.min_[1], your_mesh.max_[1])

axes.add_collection(collections.PolyCollection(your_mesh.vectors[:, :, :2],
                                               linewidth=1,
                                               facecolors=(1,1,1),alpha=1,
                                               edgecolors=(1,0,0) ))

print your_mesh.vectors.shape
pyplot.gca().set_aspect('equal')

pyplot.axis('off')
ax = pyplot.Axes(figure, [0., 0., 1., 1.], )
figure.set_dpi(72)

figure.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
figure.subplots_adjust(top = 1)
figure.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
figure.subplots_adjust(left = 0)

figure.savefig('image_refined7.png', format='png',
               transparent=True, dpi=req_dpi)  # MODIFIED
```

This produces a .png with exactly 7158x16392 pixel for me, no axes and (as far as I can tell), no missing or additional data.
As I said earlier, you need to define `dpi` in the savefig-dialog (or savefig.dpi somewhere else) and you cannot use `bbox='tight'` if you want pixel-exact figures. The floats around `req_dpi` are not needed if you run Python3 or `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: I want to be able to choose the resolution.
I want the final image have 7158 x 16392 with 72 dpi, without any borders or frames. if you look at the image, you'll see a collumn of transparent pixels that I don't want .